# How to specify which optional parameters to use in a method call?

Tags: python, wsdl, suds

I want to use optional parameter 4, not optional parameter 3.  How do i specify that my 3rd parameter in my method call is supposed to use optional parameter 4 instead of default to 3?

python code:

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client('http://x.x.x.x/mywsdl.wsdl')
client.service.getData("req_Param1", "req_Param2", "option_Param4")
```

wsdl request xml:

```
<reqparam1>?</reqparam1>
<reqparam2>?</reqparam2>
<!--Optional:-->
<optionparam3>?</optionparam3>
<!--Optional:-->
<optionparam4>?</optionparam4>
<!--Optional:-->
<optionparam5>?</optionparam5>
```

Parameter 3 needs to be unspecified but 4 does need to be specified.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah it was very simple.

```
client.service.getData(reqparam1="req_Param1", reqparam2="req_Param2", optionparam4="option_Param4")
```